# Find oldest email via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I found multiple posts regarding this topic, but I don't think they are correct.
The following script works great if you want to find the earliest/oldest item (which for my luck, it is a contact).

```
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -IncludeOldestAndNewestItems -Identity USERID | 
    Where OldestItemReceivedDate -ne $null | 
    Sort OldestItemReceivedDate | 
    Select -First 1 OldestItemReceivedDate
```

I want to find the earliest.. first email someone received.  So someone helped me creating the following:

```
# Get the folder statistics for all folders
$stats = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -IncludeOldestAndNewestItems -Identity $USERID

# Get the oldest email. Can re-use $stats for the other item types
$OldestEmail = $stats |
  Where-Object {$_.OldestItemReceivedDate -and $_.ContainerClass -eq 'IPF.Note'} |
  Sort-Object OldestItemReceivedDate |
  Select-Object ContainerClass,OldestItemReceivedDate,FolderPath -First 1

# Outputs
ContainerClass OldestItemReceivedDate FolderPath
-------------- ---------------------- ----------
IPF.Note       2/8/2016 2:07:50 PM    /Inbox
```

That previous script works great, if... the email is not on the **Purge** folder.  For some reason, when the emails are moved to the Purge folder, the ContainerClass is also removed.  I know there is an email prior to 2/8/2016, but it is on the **-Archive** **\Recoverable Items\ Purge**

Answer (score 1):

If all you're doing is trying to avoid contact matching, change your ContainerClass to:

```
$_.ContainerClass -ne 'IPF.Contact'
```

That way you won't exclude the Purges folder. Alternatively you could adjust it to:

```
-and (($_.ContainerClass -eq 'IPF.Note') -or ($_.FolderPath -match "Purges"))
```

edit: I can't make comments to reply to you yet sorry, but yes Purges has no ContainerClass. It'll still proceed just fine with the 1st option (because a $null containerclass is still not equal to 'IPF.Contact'). Did you need to include contacts in the search?